# Unicode plot markers in Python 3 and matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matplotlib, unicode

I have a plot where i use a variety of unicode characters as marker symbols in matplotlib. E.g.:

```
plot(x, y, marker=ur"$\u25B2$", markeredgecolor='#262626', linewidth=1)
```

The command above is for python 2.7 and I am passing it a unicode character for a triangle pointing up. This works fine in python 2.7 with matplotlib 1.4.x. Recently i have been trying to move to python 3.5 and i changed the above line to:

```
plot(x, y, marker=r"$\u25B2$", markeredgecolor='#262626', linewidth=1)
```

Unfortunately this does not work in python 3.5 with matplotlib 1.5.0. I cannot see what i am doing wrong. It gives me a strange type of error that i cannot make any sense of (see below). Am I not representing unicode character correctly, or is something else wrong with matplotlib itself?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py", line 2368, in parse
    result = self._expression.parseString(s)
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1125, in parseString
    raise exc
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1115, in parseString
    loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1046, in _parseCache
    value = self._parseNoCache( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 989, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 2624, in parseImpl
    return self.expr._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1046, in _parseCache
    value = self._parseNoCache( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 989, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 2378, in parseImpl
    loc, exprtokens = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1046, in _parseCache
    value = self._parseNoCache( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 989, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 2732, in parseImpl
    loc, tokens = self.expr._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1046, in _parseCache
    value = self._parseNoCache( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 989, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 2361, in parseImpl
    loc, resultlist = self.exprs[0]._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1046, in _parseCache
    value = self._parseNoCache( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1015, in _parseNoCache
    tokens = fn( instring, tokensStart, retTokens )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 779, in wrapper
    ret = func(*args[limit[0]:])
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py", line 2439, in math_string
    return self._math_expression.parseString(toks[0][1:-1])
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1125, in parseString
    raise exc
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1115, in parseString
    loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1046, in _parseCache
    value = self._parseNoCache( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 989, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 2624, in parseImpl
    return self.expr._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1046, in _parseCache
    value = self._parseNoCache( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 989, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 2766, in parseImpl
    loc, tokens = self.expr._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1046, in _parseCache
    value = self._parseNoCache( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 989, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 2624, in parseImpl
    return self.expr._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1046, in _parseCache
    value = self._parseNoCache( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 989, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 2483, in parseImpl
    ret = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1046, in _parseCache
    value = self._parseNoCache( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1015, in _parseNoCache
    tokens = fn( instring, tokensStart, retTokens )
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 779, in wrapper
    ret = func(*args[limit[0]:])
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py", line 2525, in unknown_symbol
    raise ParseFatalException(s, loc, "Unknown symbol: %s" % c)
pyparsing.ParseFatalException: Unknown symbol: \u (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RTMEditor.py", line 783, in <module>
    main()
  File "RTMEditor.py", line 776, in main
    mw = RTMEditor(args.fname[0], dwx=args.s[0], dwy=args.s[0])
  File "RTMEditor.py", line 273, in __init__
    self.render_view()
  File "RTMEditor.py", line 520, in render_view
    markeredgecolor='#262626', zorder=3, linewidth=1)
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1811, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1427, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 386, in _grab_next_args
    for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 374, in _plot_args
    seg = func(x[:, j % ncx], y[:, j % ncy], kw, kwargs)
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 281, in _makeline
    self.set_lineprops(seg, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 189, in set_lineprops
    line.set(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 937, in set
    ret.extend([func(v)])
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 1072, in set_marker
    self._marker.set_marker(marker)
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/markers.py", line 255, in set_marker
    self._recache()
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/markers.py", line 193, in _recache
    self._marker_function()
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/markers.py", line 331, in _set_mathtext_path
    usetex=rcParams['text.usetex'])
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 445, in __init__
    usetex=usetex)
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 529, in text_get_vertices_codes
    ismath=ismath)
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 148, in get_text_path
    prop, s)
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 240, in get_glyphs_mathtext
    s, self.DPI, prop)
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py", line 3118, in parse
    box = self._parser.parse(s, font_output, fontsize, dpi)
  File "/Users/dchandan/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py", line 2374, in parse
    six.text_type(err)]))
ValueError: 
\u25B2
^
Unknown symbol: \u (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is remove the `r` from `r"$\u25B2$"`. The `r` marks the string as a raw string literal, meaning that escape sequences are not translated.

```
In [38]: x = np.linspace(0,10)

In [39]: y = np.sin(np.linspace(0,10))

In [40]: plt.plot(x, y, marker="$\u25b2$")
Out[40]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x110768da0>]
```

[image]

Comment: That worked! So why was the 'r' required for python 2, but not python 3? I removed the 'u' because python 3 strings are default unicode. But I don't understand what 'r' does for python 3.

Comment: @deepak the `r` actually isn't required for Py2 (I'm using 2.7.10 and matplotlib 1.5.0), but the `u` *is* required to indicate that it's a Unicode string. Since all strings in Python 3 are Unicode, the `u` isn't required, although if it's there it'll just be ignored.

Comment: I got the following error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u25b2' in position 231: ordinal not in range(128)